# How to rename a field in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I have an index in Elasticsearch with the following field mapping:

```
{
    "version_data": {
        "properties": {
            "title": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "raw": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            },
            "updated_at": {
                "type": "date"
            },
            "updated_by": {
                "type": "keyword"
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I have already created some documents in it and now want to rename `version_data` field with `_version_data`.
Is there any way in the Elasticsearch to rename a field within the mapping and in documents?

Answer (score 4):

The closest thing is the [alias data type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/alias.html).

In your mapping you could link it from the old to the new name like this:

```
PUT test/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "_version_data": {
      "type": "alias",
      "path": "version_data"
    }
  }
}
```

BTW I would generally avoid leading underscored since those normally used for internal fields like `_id`.

Comment: Xeraa have the best answer. and _ prefix is only for metafields, so for vesion_data it can make sens. If you want to really change the file you will have to reindex.